# Why "php code" change in a bootstrap modal box?

Tags: javascript, php

Hi When I use boostrap modal box ; Than php code takes only the first item of my table..;

$sonuc['proje_ismi'] is working normal in button and change everyline as database:

But when I put it on bootstarp modal box, it only takes the first item. Why is that?

And how can I solve it with a simple way?

Thanks for advices.

```
<td> 

  <button type="button" id="view_files" name="view_files" data-name="'.$proje_ismi.'"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="view_files btn btn-default btn-sm"><font  size="2" >
                <?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?></font></button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" >

  <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Proje Dosyaları</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">


  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
  <th>Dosya İsimleri </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  <th>
  <div class="modal-body" id="file_list">
  <?php   
  $projeler =  $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ;
  echo $projeler;

  $folder = array_filter(glob(''.$projeler.'/*.*'));




  print_r($folder);
  ?>

</th>
  </tr>
  </table>  


  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
                </td>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate IDs in the table. IDs should be unique.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean?. There is no Table "ID" in here.

Comment: This looks like one row of a table, and I see things like `id="myModal"` and `id="file_list"`. If this is part of a loop, that will be on every row.

Comment: yes it is one row a table... and it connect to mysql when I add a file to database. it repeats for all rows.

The problem is when I got the code outside of the MODAL BOX of boostrap.. code working well and I got all files in row.. but the problem is I wont wanna see the files in row I want them to be in a Modal Box...

Answer (score 0):

For information:

I couldnt solve the problem with bootsrap but I solved problem with lightbox css...

I download lightbox2-2.11.1 css documant and did the following at the web site below:

> https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#help